# Функция для создания массивов разных размерностей с разным числом элементов

Tags: c, массивы

Нужно на C написать более-менее универсальную функцию, которая позволяет создавать массив произвольной (известной заранее) размерности с произвольным (известным заранее числом элементов). Предполагается вот такая сигнатура (тип аргументов `double` и `int` для длин):

```
void grid_generator(double */*произвольное количество *, 1, 2, до 4*/ pgrid, const int size_1, /* сколько-то размеров */, const double value /* инициализирующее значение */)
```

Как правильно это сделать, и вообще, можно ли?

Comment: Поскольку элементы массива любой размерности размещаются в памяти последовательно, то вполне возможно. Выделяете память равную произведению всех размерностей на `sizeof(double)` и заполняете ее списком значений. В случае для  `double` можно использовать не полный список (например, ограниченный `NaN`).  Только прототип вызова лучше переработать.  Для  конкретизации ознакомьтесь с [variable argument lists](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start)

Comment: Вам надо ещё позаботься и освобождении ресурса. Вам нужна функция возвращающая указатель в нутом которой будет аллоцироватся память под размерность массива. Вопрос в другом - корректное освобождение ресурса. Создайте универсальную структуру с указателем и размерностями - это обеспечит надежное аллоцирование и деаллоцирование ресурса.

Comment: Вы пишете *`"массив произвольной (известной заранее) размерности с произвольным (известным заранее числом элементов)"`*. Если эти величины известны до компиляции (т.е. это константы в исходном коде), то м.б. более эффективно написать набор **макросов**, которые делают такие массивы (структуры) при компиляции. Впрочем, без примерных набросков вашего кода, использующего эти массивы и понимания задач советовать что-то конкретное трудно.

Comment: Может быть имеет смысл разнести создание массивов в программе на стадии компиляции и их инициализацию уже при исполнении. Далеко не всегда один универсальный способ на самом деле хорош (как в плане эффективности работы, так и в плане удобства его использования)

Answer (score 3):

Язык Си не предусматривает стандартных (синтаксических) средств для передачи массива с произвольным количеством размерностей в функцию и доступа там к его элементам способом, аналогичным тому, как мы обращаемся к массиву с известным числом размерностей.

Поэтому, если все же хочется работать с такими массивами (разной размерности) в функции, то придется моделировать их, базируясь на доступе к элементам одномерного массива.

Например, если у нас есть трехмерный массив `double mdar[M][N][K]`, то для доступа к произвольному элементу мы пишем `mdar[i][j][k]`. Зная, что компилятор размещает в памяти все элементы такого массива последовательно, для моделирования доступа к тому же элементу через одномерный массив можно написать следующее: `double *a = &mdar[0][0][0]; a[i * N * K + j * K + k]`.

Таким образом,  в функцию, которая будет работать с массивом произвольной размерности нужно передать информацию о начале массива в памяти, количестве его размерностей, числе элементов в каждой размерности (на самом деле количество элементов "высшей размерности" не важно (см. `a[i * N * K + j * K + k]`)) и массив индексов (размером в число размерностей многомерного массива). Содержимое этого массива является аналогом `[i][j][k]` в традиционной записи.

Информацию, нужную для доступа к элементам многомерного массива (точнее всех массивов с одним и тем же количеством размерностей и одинаковым размером "низших размерностей")  можно представить вот в такой структуре:

```
struct nda_descr {
  size_t ndim;          // количество размерностей массива
  size_t dim_size[];    // в реальной программе нужно обеспечить
                        // массив размером `ndim - 1` в котором находятся
                        // размеры (включающие размеры по размерностям следующих уровней)
                        // по всем "низшим размерностям"
};
```

(Если это непонятно (извините, согласен, сразу понять такой текст в комментарии  сложно), то надеюсь, код функций `nda_getix()` и `nda_fill_descr()` прояснит ситуацию)

Функция

```
size_t
nda_getix (struct nda_descr *d, size_t ijk[])
{
  size_t ix = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < d->ndim - 1; i++)
    ix += d->dim_size[i] * ijk[i];

  return ix + ijk[d->ndim - 1];
}
```

для данного дескриптора многомерного массива и списка индексов по всем его размерностям (от "высшей" к "низшей") возвращает индекс для доступа к "одномерному аналогу".

Для построения дескрипторов многомерных массивов, их создания в динамической памяти и заполнения можно предложить, например, следующий набор функций:

```
// заполняет дескриптор массива информацией о его размерностях
// поле .ndim дескриптора уже должно быть инициализировано
// количеством размерностей
struct nda_descr *
nda_fill_descr (struct nda_descr *d, size_t dims[])
{
  size_t n_items = 1;

  for (ssize_t i = d->ndim - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    n_items *= dims[i];
    d->dim_size[i - 1] = n_items;
  }

  return d;
}

// создает в динамической памяти дескриптор массива
// размерности `ndim` с заданными в массиве `dims[]`
// размерами (количеством элементов) по каждой размерности
struct nda_descr *
nda_create_descr (size_t ndim, size_t dims[])
{
  struct nda_descr *d = malloc(sizeof(*d) + (ndim - 1) * sizeof(size_t));
  if (!d)
    return 0;

  d->ndim = ndim;
  return nda_fill_descr(d, dims);
}

// создает в динамической памяти многомерный массив
// в соответствии с ранее заполненным дескриптором `d`,
// размером `n` "высших размерностей" 
// для элементов размером `item_size` байт каждый
// и копирует в него инициализирующие данные по указателю `data`
//    (если `data` == NULL, то инициализация не производится)
void *
nda_create_fill_array (struct nda_descr *d, size_t n, size_t item_size, void *data)
{
  size_t n_items = d->dim_size[0] * n;
  void *array = malloc(n_items * item_size);

  return array ? (data ? memcpy(array, data, n_items * item_size) : array) : 0;
}
```

И на их основе написать вот  такую, семантически эквивалентную функции в вопросе, функцию (вместо списка (типа `va_list` ) элементов инициализации я предлагаю передавать массив элементов).

```
void *
nda_create_fill_array_descr (struct nda_descr **pdscr, size_t ndim, size_t dims[],
                size_t item_size, void *fill_data)
{
  if (!(*pdscr = nda_create_descr(ndim, dims)))
    return 0;

  void *array = nda_create_fill_array(*pdscr, dims[0], item_size, fill_data);
  if (!array) {
    free(*pdscr);
    *pdscr = 0;
  }

  return array;
}
```

и ряд вспомогательных, для удобства манипулирования такими массивами, скажем, для начала:

```
size_t
nda_items (struct nda_descr *d, size_t upper_dim_size)
{
  return d->dim_size[0] * upper_dim_size;
}
```

Примеры использования:

```
  double mx[3][3][3] = {
    {
      {111., 112., 113.},
      {121., 122., 123.},
      {131., 132., 133.}
    },
    {
      {211., 212., 213.},
      {221., 222., 223.},
      {231., 232., 233.}
    },
    {
      {311., 312., 313.},
      {321., 322., 323.},
      {331., 332., 333.}
    }

  };
```

Это трехмерный массив, который используется для инициализации.

Создаем трехмерный массив, который заполняем данными из `mx`

```
  struct nda_descr *a3d;
  double *a3 = nda_create_fill_array_descr(&a3d, 3, (size_t []){3, 3, 3}, sizeof(a3[0]), mx);
```

Тело массива (данные) расположены по указателю `a3`, его дескриптор по указателю `a3d`.

Теперь напечатаем количество элементов в созданном массиве и элемент `a3[2][0][0]` (понятно, что мы моделируем доступ к нему, прямо так написать синтаксически невозможно) вместе с индексом в `a3[]` по которому фактически происходит доступ:

```
#define NDA_IJK (size_t [])

  printf("a3 n_items: %zd\n", nda_items(a3d, 3));
  size_t ii = nda_getix(a3d, NDA_IJK{2, 0, 0});
  printf("a3 [2][0][0] %f [%zd]\n", a3[ii], ii);
```

Можно смоделировать трехмерный массив, аналогичный `a[2][3][3]`, разместив в одной структуре (далее ее можно передавать в разные функции) дескриптор массива и указатель на данные, инициализировав их заданными непосредственно в списке аргументов величинами.

```
  struct  {
    double *a32;
    size_t upper_dim_size;
    struct nda_descr d;
    size_t sz[2];  // обеспечим нужный для трехмерного массива размер поля .d.dim_size[]
  } adss;

  adss.d.ndim = 3;
  nda_fill_descr(&adss.d, NDA_IJK{2, 3, 3});
  adss.a32 = nda_create_fill_array(&adss.d, adss.upper_dim_size = 2, sizeof(double),                   
         (double [][3][3]) {
         {
            {311., 312., 313.}, {321., 322., 323.}, {331., 332., 333.}
         },
         {
            {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}
         }});
```

и напечатать элемент `[1][1][1]` (индексы в ранее заполненном массиве `ijk[]`), а также количество элементов (еще один пример, демонстрирующий использование не указателя на дескриптор, а самой структуры дескриптора)

```
  printf("a32 [1][1][1] %f\n", adss.a32[nda_getix(&adss.d, ijk)]);
  printf("a32 n_items: %zd\n", nda_items(&adss.d, adss.upper_dim_size));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Разбираюсь с обоими вариантами... Все время думал про то, что любой массив в памяти - одномерный. Думал, что поможет вот такой способ, с помощью [кривой Мортона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0), но пока не придумал, как быть с "неквадратными" подмассивами... В принципе там в теории всё равно, но может оказаться, что кривая будет делать несимметричный обход, не доходить до конца.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
void FillArray(void *array, double value, size_t dim, ...)
{
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, dim);

    /* Вычисляем количество элементов в массиве: */

    size_t totalElementsCount = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        totalElementsCount *= va_arg(argumentList, size_t);

    /* Присваиваем каждому элементу значение аргумента value: */

    double *arrayPointer = array;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < totalElementsCount; ++i)
        arrayPointer[i] = value;

    va_end(argumentList);
}
```

Предполагается что после параметра `dim` будут дано количество элементов в каждом измерении массива. Например:

```
double a[3][4][5];
FillArray(a, 3.1415, 3, 3, 4, 5);
```

---

Приведенный выше код заполняет уже существующий многомерный массив. Гораздо интереснее будет создать массив с нуля. Формально говоря, создать именно *массив* (в терминах C) невозможно. Создать получиться только т. н. разряжённый массив (англ. jagged array).

Для начала попробуем сделать это вручную:

```
const size_t dimensions[3] = {2, 2, 3};
const double value = 3.141593;

double ***array = malloc(dimensions[0] * sizeof(*array));

for (size_t i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; ++i) {
    array[i] = malloc(dimensions[1] * sizeof(*array[i]));

    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; ++j) {
        array[i][j] = malloc(dimensions[2] * sizeof(*array[i][j]));

        for (size_t k = 0; k < dimensions[2]; ++k)
            array[i][j][k] = value;
    }
}
```

После недолгих раздумий можно прийти к такой функции:

```
void *createAndFillDoubleArray(size_t n, const size_t dimensions[n], size_t dim, double value)
{
    if (dim < n - 1) {
        void **array = malloc(dimensions[dim] * sizeof(double *));

        for (size_t i = 0; i < dimensions[dim]; ++i)
            array[i] = createAndFillDoubleArray(n, dimensions, dim + 1, value);

        return array;
    } else {
        double *array = malloc(dimensions[dim] * sizeof(double));

        for (size_t i = 0; i < dimensions[dim]; ++i)
            array[i] = value;

        return array;
    }
}
```

Использовать которую можно так:

```
double ***array_1 = createAndFillArray(3, (size_t []) {3, 3, 4}, 0, 3.141593);
double **array_2 = createAndFillArray(2, (size_t []) {1, 4}, 0, 3.141593);
```

Параметр `dim` в данном случае служебный и используется в качестве счетчика в рекурсии. Не очень красиво, но над функцией все-равно еще нужно подумать. Имеет смысл отделить создание массива от его заполнения и реализовать функцию освобождения выделенной памяти.

*Надеюсь, память нигде не переинтерпретируется. Можно [попробовать](https://ideone.com/04oG1u) код в Ideone.*

Comment: Массив, требуемый в тексте вопроса, не создается, но в качестве затравки совершенно годно

Comment: @avp, я, видимо, не правильно понял вопрос. Мы, конечно, можем создать динамический «многомерный» массив. Но ведь формально этот  массив вовсе и не массив. Тем более не многомерный, а просто разрежённым… Это меня и смутило. Завтра дополню ответ. В любом случае спасибо за замечание :-)

Comment: Можно и обычный массив  создать (malloc-ом). И вернуть его адрес. Или первый аргумент сделать указателем на указатель и тогда адрес массива туда класть. / На самом деле, если ТС толковый, то вашего существующего примера ему за глаза хватит, а иначе может оно ему все и вообще не надо?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, я внимательно их изучаю и думаю, что делать. Больше всего заинтересовало использование первого аргумента как указатель на указатель и класть туда адрес первой ячейки. Только что делать, если я задаю, скажем, четырехмерный массив? Как "размотать" назад указатели, зная значение dim?..
Увы, уважаемый @avp , надо. И я крепко подзабыл Си, но теперь упускать его больше не намерен.

Comment: @eanmos, спасибо большое! Буду ждать дополнения, потом напишу сам и покажу, что получилось, мне очень ценны Ваши комментарии и ответы.

Comment: @DJNZ, я обновил ответ.

Comment: @avp, я обновил ответ. Можете посмотреть?

Comment: @eanmos, ну отчего же не получится создать обычный сишный (в котором все элементы расположены подряд) массив? Вы совершенно логично передаете третьим аргументам массив размерностей. В таком случае достаточно перемножить его элементы и мы получим количество элементов создаваемого многомерного  массива (скажем, `asize`). Осталось вызвать `malloc(asize * sizeof(double))`. Проще всего просто вернуть полученный адрес из функции создания массива. Другой вопрос с написанием удобной инфраструктуры для доступа к элементам таких массивов и вообще, манипулирования ими на любом уровне кода.

Comment: @avp, я имел в виду формальный массив (*array type* — `T []`). Вы предлагаете сделать просто одномерный массив достаточного размера, а я так понимаю, что вопрос именно в создание многомерного jagged array.

Comment: @eanmos, совершенно верно -- одномерный достаточной вместимости (т.е. абсолютно *в духе программирования на Си*). Какие мысли у ТС по поводу структуры массивов для его задачи пусть он четко расскажет сам (в тексте вопроса)